# how to change background color of a label in QT

Tags: qt, label, qlabel

I am developing calculator using qt framework. I have put a label for display the entered number and answer so I want to change the color of this label. How can I do that.

```
label = new QLabel("0",this);//label for the text inputs
label -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(75,25),QSize(50,200)));
```

please help

Comment: Those answers doesn't solved my problem

Comment: Then you probably didn't ask correctly what you want, or didn't apply it correctly, because both answer will change the background color of your label.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html)

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel("Hello");
label->setStyleSheet("background: red");
```

Comment: its working and another problem is when this applies whole the label getting red and when I am re sizing the label size(because I want small highlighted area ) the position of the label is changing. 
How can I overcome this problem.

Comment: _when this applies whole the label getting red_ Yes, the background will be red, as you asked. _the position of the label is changing_ This has nothing to do with background color.

Comment: instead of setting geometry, consider using layouts

Answer (score 1):

setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");